# Adobe Air Javascript Debugging

Tags: javascript, air, dreamweaver, aptana

I've been looking for a way to debug Adobe Air Javascript apps with the 2.7 version of the SDK.

Supposedly Aptana Studio only supports v2.0 and only with Aptana Studio v2.0 (the newest is 3.0).

Does Dreamweaver 5.5 support it?  Are there any alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this will never happen.  I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Three years and still no support.  Looks like Max was right. :-(

Comment: :D  @Max: I can't stop laughing at your answer. Curious and funny!!.

Comment: :) The best answer now is to use node-webkit, which just blows away what Adobe Air ever was going to be on the desktop!